# Check wether a MongoDB field value is present inside an field array of the same document

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

this is my mongoDB document, i want check if the date in sessionDate is present inside the array unavailableDates.

This is my schema

```
const adminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
sessionDate:{
    type:Date
    
},
unavailableDates:{
   type: [Date]
},
 email:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
    min:6,
    max:255
},
password:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
    min:6,
    max:1024
},
});
 module.exports = mongoose.model('Admin',adminSchema);
```

This is my mongoose document

```
_id: objectId('6332d9846c4803d9ffc53bb0') 
"email":"someemail@mail.com"

 "password":"$2b$10$0ixZcynrlRhHQs14xJzPhO5Zn5scbWMrUFwbC/S6nrDI7qe9ZeJ0e"
unavailableDates: Array
0: 2022-09-08T18:30:00.000+00:00
1: 2022-10-09T18:30:00.000+00:00
2: 2021-12-31T18:30:00.000+00:00
3: 2022-01-01T18:30:00.000+00:00  
sessionDate: 2021-12-31T18:30:00.000+00:00
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if at least one of unavailableDates array entries is same as sessionDate this is one option:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 "$match": {
   "$expr": {
     "$in": [
        "$sessionDate",
        "$unavailableDates"
      ]
     }
   }
 }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f3PcHCFjKNN)